# Complicated Sql Case Statement Getting the Wrong Result Set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case

**The Original Access Query**

```
IIf([Package Type]="Bar",10,IIf([upper limit unit]="g",([UL3]*[weight factor]),[piece wt (g)]*[Upper Limit Factor])) AS [Upper Limit (g)]
```

**The SQL Conversion**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Package Type] = 'Bar' Then 10 
CASE WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] = 'g' Then ([UL3)] * [Weight Factor]
ELSE [Peice Wt(g)] * [Upper Limit Factor] END AS [Upper Limit (g)]
```

I am getting a "Syntax error near the keyword ELSE", the individual parts of the query work perfectly well.

How do I reference multiple `case` statements within a `case` statement? PLEASE HELP

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN [Package Type] = 'Bar' THEN 10
    CASE WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] = 'g' 
           THEN CASE WHEN [Package Type] != NULL
                     THEN ([mav (g)] - [scale deviation factor] - [tare variation factor (g)]) / NULLIF ([weight factor], 0) 
           WHEN (mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                 / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) 
                 - CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                 / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                 = 0 
           THEN CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
           WHEN (mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                 / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) 
                 - CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                 / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) > 0 
                 AND 
                 (mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                 / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) 
                 - CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                 / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int)  < 0.51 
           THEN CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                + [Rounding Factor1] ELSE CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - pl.[Scale Deviation Factor] - nwmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                / NULLIF (nwmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) + [Rounding Factor2] * NULLIF ( [Weight Factor],0)
           ELSE CASE WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] != 'g' 
                     THEN ([Label Wt (g)] / [Pcs Per Unit]) * [Upper Limit Factor] END AS [Upper Limit (g)]

FROM
    dbo.[Net Weight Master Data] nwmd
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.[Production Lines] pl ON nwmd.[Production Line] = pl.[Production Line] 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations] mav ON nwmd.[Label Wt (g)] = mav.[Labeled Quantity (g)] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.ItemDescription I ON nwmd.[Unit UPC Base Item] = I.[Unit UPC Base Item]
ORDER BY 
    nwmd.[Unit UPC Base Item], 
    nwmd.[Production Line]
```

Comment: Indentation and aligning your CASE ... WHEN / ELSE ... ENDs beneath eachother might shed some light here?

Comment: You can't ping users who haven't interacted on the post. So adding a comment to a user won't do anything but add noise.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry Sir wont happen next time!!!!

Comment: I formatted your select/case statement, and as you can see you have many case/when conditions, but not all have proper ELSE/END to terminate.  Also, the other thing I did was adjusted to use ALIAS names to your tables to clarify readability instead of super long table references throughout the code.  Finally, make additional adjustments to show all alias.[column names] so we know where things are coming from.  It is ambiguous when not knowing where columns originate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Using all your appreciated help i was still facing syntax issues i fixed those by placing the "End" at the respective position and removed the extra "Else" in the query and the final query that worked is:

```
SELECT [wmd].[Unit UPC Base Item], 
    CASE WHEN [Package Type] = 'Bar' Then 10  
            WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] != 'g' THEN ([Label Wt (g)] / [Pcs Per Unit])* ([Upper Limit Factor]) 
                WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] = 'g' THEN 
    CASE WHEN [Package Type] IS NOT NULL THEN ([mav (g)] - [scale deviation factor] - [tare variation factor (g)]) / NULLIF ([weight factor], 0) 
             WHEN (mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - wmd.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                      / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) 
                      - CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - [wmd].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                      / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                      = 0 THEN CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - [wmd].[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                       / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
             WHEN (mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - [wmd].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                      / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) 
                      - CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - [wmd].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                      / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) > 0 AND 
                      (mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - [wmd].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                      / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) 
                      - CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - [wmd].[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                      / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                      < 0.51 THEN CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - [wmd].[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                       / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                      + [Rounding Factor1] 
             ELSE CAST((mav.[MAV (g)] - prod.[Scale Deviation Factor] - [wmd].[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                       / NULLIF (wmd.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) + [Rounding Factor2]  
              END *([Weight Factor])
              END AS [UpperLimit(g)] 

FROM         dbo.[Net Weight Master Data] AS wmd LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.[Production Lines] AS prod ON wmd.[Production Line] = prod.[Production Line] INNER JOIN
                      dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations] AS mav ON wmd.[Label Wt (g)] = mav.[Labeled Quantity (g)] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.ItemDescription ON wmd.[Unit UPC Base Item] = dbo.ItemDescription.[Unit UPC Base Item]
ORDER BY wmd.[Unit UPC Base Item], wmd.[Production Line]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `4` `CASE` and only 1 `END`, so that won't work.

It's a big mess to wade through, but ideally you can break apart common criteria to clean this up, using multiple steps is easier to read than one honking nested `CASE` query.

At the least you need more `END`, and indenting will help isolate errors:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN [Package Type] = 'Bar' 
     THEN 10 
     ELSE CASE WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] = 'g' 
               THEN CASE WHEN [Package Type] IS NOT NULL 
                         THEN ([mav (g)] - [scale deviation factor] - [tare variation factor (g)]) / NULLIF ([weight factor], 0) 
                         WHEN (MAV.[MAV (g)] - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                                / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) - CAST((MAV.[MAV (g)] - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] 
                                - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) = 0 
                         THEN CAST((MAV.[MAV (g)] - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                            / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                         WHEN (MAV.[MAV (g)] - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                            / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) - CAST((MAV.[MAV (g)] - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] 
                            - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) > 0 AND 
                            (MAV.[MAV (g)] - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) 
                            / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) - CAST((MAV.[MAV (g)] - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] 
                            - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)]) / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) 
                            < 0.51 
                        THEN CAST((MAV.[MAV (g)] - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                            / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) + [Rounding Factor1] 
                        ELSE CAST((MAV.[MAV (g)]  
                          - PL.[Scale Deviation Factor] - NWMD.[Tare Variation Factor (g)])
                           / NULLIF (NWMD.[Weight Factor], 0) AS Int) + [Rounding Factor2] * NULLIF ( [Weight Factor],0) 
                        ELSE CASE WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] != 'g' --Double ELSE!
                                  THEN ([Label Wt (g)] / [Pcs Per Unit]) * [Upper Limit Factor] 
                             END
                  END
        END
END AS [Upper Limit (g)]
FROM         dbo.[Net Weight Master Data] NWMD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.[Production Lines] PL ON NWMD.[Production Line] = PL.[Production Line] INNER JOIN
                      dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations] MAV ON NWMD.[Label Wt (g)] = MAV.[Labeled Quantity (g)] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.ItemDescription ID ON NWMD.[Unit UPC Base Item] = ID.[Unit UPC Base Item]
ORDER BY NWMD.[Unit UPC Base Item], NWMD.[Production Line]
```

Update: Also spotted 2 `ELSE` in one `CASE`, noted above with `--Double ELSE!`, you can only have one `ELSE` per `CASE`.  As Aaron pointed out, you've also got a `!= NULL` in there, you need `IS NOT NULL` there. Additionally added table aliases to clean things up further.

Comment: Also `!= NULL` does not make sense.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I corrected the above changes, i am still getting "An Expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" near Case When [Upper Limit Unit] = 'g' And "incorrect syntax near the keyword AS"

Comment: @HackGod555 how did you resolve the double `ELSE` noted above?

Comment: @GoatCO IIf([UL2]>0 And [UL2]<0.51 the inner else was used to evaluate everything that is not >0 and is not <0.51 so i did the same but removed the else and added a when "not >0 and is not <0.51" then condition. Now i have one massive else for 4 case statements.

Answer (score 0):

Although I pre-formatted your original to see the failures of alignment of case/when/then constructs, I have gone a step further to simplify the readability by doing a prequery of the data elements by creating new simplified columns of your "mav - scale - tare" and NULLIF( weight factor ), AND again as a single "DivideTest" via "mav - scale - tare" / NULLIF( weight factor, 0 ) from your raw data.

This allows the outer query to use these simplified column names as basis of the case construct for readability.

I still do not know what it is you are trying to get at for your respective breaks, but hopefully this version will make it more clear what you are TRYING to get at.  AND I KNOW I DO NOT HAVE PROPER ELSE/END COMPONENTS as it is unclear what you are trying to get at.  Finally, I would hope you know that divide by zero is an invalid value, so when you are testing for NULLIF( [weight factor], 0 ) might cause an issue within your case constructs.

```
SELECT
      CASE WHEN PQ.pkgType = 'Bar' 
           THEN 10
           ELSE CASE WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] = 'g' 
                     THEN CASE WHEN PQ.pkgType != NULL
                                   THEN PQ.DivideTest
                               WHEN PQ.DivideTest - CAST( PQ.DivideTest AS Int) = 0 
                                   THEN CAST( PQ.DivideTest AS Int) = 0 
                               WHEN PQ.DivideTest - CAST( PQ.DivideTest AS Int) > 0 
                                           AND 
                                    PQ.DivideTest - CAST( PQ.DivideTest AS Int) < 0.51
                                  THEN CAST( PQ.DivideTest AS Int) + PQ.roundFactor1

                                  ELSE CAST( PQ.DivideTest AS Int) + PQ.roundFactor2 * PQ.WeightFactor
                                  END
                     ELSE CASE WHEN [Upper Limit Unit] != 'g' 
                     THEN PQ.notGWeight END AS [Upper Limit (g)]
           END
   from 
      ( SELECT 
              [Package Type] pkgType,
              [Upper Limit Unit] upperLimitUnit,
              NULLIF (nwmd.[weight factor], 0)  as weightFactor,
              (mav.[mav (g)] - pl.[scale deviation factor] - nwmd.[tare variation factor (g)]) / NULLIF (nwmd.[weight factor], 0) as DivideTest,
              [Rounding Factor1] roundFactor1,
              [Rounding Factor2] roundFactor2,
              ([Label Wt (g)] / [Pcs Per Unit]) * [Upper Limit Factor] notGWeight
           FROM
              dbo.[Net Weight Master Data] nwmd
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Production Lines] pl
                    ON nwmd.[Production Line] = pl.[Production Line] 
                 INNER JOIN dbo.[Maximum Allowable Variations] mav
                    ON nwmd.[Label Wt (g)] = mav.[Labeled Quantity (g)] 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ItemDescription I 
                    ON nwmd.[Unit UPC Base Item] = I.[Unit UPC Base Item]
           ORDER BY 
              nwmd.[Unit UPC Base Item], 
              nwmd.[Production Line] ) PQ
```

Comment: This whole solution is based of an Access Query : IIf([Package Type]="Bar",10,IIf([upper limit unit]="g",([UL3]*[weight factor]),[piece wt (g)]*[Upper Limit Factor])) AS [Upper Limit (g)] Which i then converter to SQL to form Case When [Package Type] = 'Bar' Then 10 Case When [Upper Limit Unit]  = 'g' then [ul3] * [weight factor] else [piece weight]* [upper limit factor] END AS [Upper Limit (g)]. The problem occurs when there are multiple case statements involved and causing syntax issues, i am still troubleshooting the query.

Comment: @HackGod555, then I would suggest posting the original Access query  by editing your original question and putting it there as a note... something like:  BTW, the original query is from This Access Query...